# NotificationCenter observer is “mutated after capture by sendable closure”

Tags: swift, notificationcenter

Consider this simple class:

```swift
import Foundation

class ExampleClass {

    init() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        var observer: NSObjectProtocol? = nil
        // A warning is emitted for the next line
        observer = notificationCenter.addObserver(
            forName: .NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil
        ) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.doSomething()
            notificationCenter.removeObserver(observer!)
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("We got the notification")
    }

}
```

This code uses the exact pattern that Apple suggests in [their documentation for `NotificationCenter.addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver#), where the `NotificationCenter` gives us some opaque token that conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`, and we later use that token to remove the observer.

Recently, though, this code has started to produce a warning. On the line where `observer` is assigned, the compiler complains that

> 'observer' mutated after capture by sendable closure

I understand where the compiler is coming from here: if `observer` is a value type, then the closure will indeed get an “old” version of it. This code does work, though, which suggests to me that either `addObserver()` returns a reference type, or else that it returns a value-type handle into data that `NotificationCenter` is storing itself. (It’s unfortunate that Apple doesn’t give us a more specific return type for the method.)

Does this warning indicate an actual problem in this case? If so, what’s the best alternative pattern to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the observer on the object itself:

```swift
import Foundation

class ExampleClass {

    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    init() {
        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
        observer = notificationCenter.addObserver(
            forName: .NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground,
            object: nil,
            queue: nil
        ) { [weak self] _ in
            if let self {
                self.doSomething()
                notificationCenter.removeObserver(self.observer!)
            }
        }
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("We got the notification")
    }

}
```

This workaround silences the warning, and it shouldn’t change the semantics of the program in a meaningful way. It’s a bit less elegant, in that a variable that could have stayed local to `init` (and its closures) is now exposed to the entire class, but it should have the same effect as the previous version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "container" class (reference type) to store a value of any kind (reference type or value type). Then, instead of using  `NSObjectProtocol` directly, you can use that "container".

Compiler will not display warning anymore, simply because "container" is a reference type.

Here is a Playground demo:

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let notificationName = NSNotification.Name("MyNotification")

open class MutableReference<T> {

   public var value: T

   public init(value: T) {
      self.value = value
      print("+ Initialized reference")
   }

   deinit {
      print("~ Destroying reference")
   }
}

class ExampleClass {

   init() {
      let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
      let reference = MutableReference<NSObjectProtocol>(value: NSObject()) // Putting "dummy" value, which will be replaced few lines below
      let observer = notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: notificationName, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
         self?.doSomething()
         print("Will unsubscribe...")
         notificationCenter.removeObserver(reference.value)
      }
      reference.value = observer
      print("+ Created Example class")
   }

   deinit {
      print("~ Destroying Example class")
   }

   func doSomething() {
      print("We got the notification")
   }

}

var example: ExampleClass! = ExampleClass()
print("= Will sent notification #1")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
print("= Will sent notification #2")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)
example = nil
```

The output will be:

```
+ Initialized reference
+ Created Example class
= Will sent notification #1
We got the notification
Will unsubscribe...
~ Destroying reference
= Will sent notification #2
~ Destroying Example class
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern alternative is a `Combine` publisher

```
import Combine

class ExampleClass {
    
    private var subscription : AnyCancellable?
    
    init() {
        subscription = NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: .NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackground)
            .sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.doSomething()
            }
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        print("We got the notification")
        subscription?.cancel()
        subscription = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Any` instead of `NSObjectProtocol` as type of the variable seems to get rid of the warning.